# must specify an absolute path maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, settings

I have the following in my settings.xml

```
<profile>
  <id>default</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true></activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <eclipse.location>/Applications/eclipse</eclipse.location>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

But I keep getting an error on this line in pom.xml in my project:

```
        <systemPath>$(eclipse.location)/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_${appengine.target.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${appengine.target.version}/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar</systemPath>
```

Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.google.appengine:appengine-local-runtime:jar must specify an absolute path but is $(eclipse.location)/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar

From the output from mvn clean I can see that the settings.xml file is read.

```
 [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
 [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/xxx/.m2/settings.xml
 [DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/xxx/.m2/repository
```

But I get the same error as above:

```
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.google.appengine:appengine-local-runtime:jar must specify an absolute path but is $(eclipse.location)/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.6/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar @ line 274, column 16
```

Comment: You don't get failures `<activeByDefault>true></activeByDefault>` this looks wrong.

Comment: I recommend never use systemPath. You should better start using a repository manager and put your artifacts there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use curly brackets instead of parentheses to refer to the properties:

```
${eclipse.location}
```

Comment: Thanks. Been staring at this thing for a while now, did not see it.